# How to automatically promote an Azure web app to production, if it passes all the integration tests

Tags: azure, integration-testing, continuous-delivery

I've got an ASP.NET MVC web app with a set of Selenium UI integration tests for it. I want to put this in Azure, and apply continuous delivery like this:

1. I commit a change to the Git repository
2. Azure notices the commit, gets the latest code, builds it, and deploys it to some test environment
3. Azure runs my unit tests on the code, and fails the build if any tests fail
4. Azure runs my integration tests on the test environment, and fails the build if any tests fail
5. If all tests pass, promote the code to production

This seems like a logical pipeline to me but I've struggled to get it working.

I've managed to get to step 3. by creating two web apps, e.g. Muppet and MuppetStaging. The MuppetStaging environment is automatically updated on each commit, so that's a great start. I edited the `deploy.cmd` to perform unit tests. This fails the build when the unit tests fail. That's great too.

The integration testing is the hard bit. Before the deployment has been completed, I can't integration test the current build - because it's not been deployed yet. The best I could do was integration test the *previous* version... but not the pending version. And even if I could, how would I then promote a successful build to production?

I know there is a "staging slot" concept but I don't want to have to press a "Swap" button to get my change into production, that would defeat the concept of CD. There is also an "Auto Swap" but again I don't think this takes integration testing into account.

I've been looking at tutorials relating to this kind of issue but no-one seems to have my requirements exactly... so either it's not possible or I'm doing it all wrong.

Comment: A CI tool like Jenkins or others should be able to accomplish this task. You can go build -> staging deploy -> unit test -> integration test -> swap each upon success of pervious step. You have already done the hard part, a simple CI setup will help you put them in order.

Comment: Yeah I've started setting up a Jenkins server on my PC, and once I finish configuring it I'll probably put it in its own Azure web app as described here: http://donovanbrown.com/post/2016/02/28/How-to-install-Jenkins-in-an-Azure-Web-App

Answer (score 0):

let me see if i can help and answer some of your question.

> The integration testing is the hard bit. Before the deployment has
>   been completed, I can't integration test the current build - because
>   it's not been deployed yet.

There is post deployment hook that trigger after everything is deployed but still within the deployment process.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks

> There is also an "Auto Swap" but again I don't think this takes
>   integration testing into account.

if you do testing with post deployment hook, if test failed which will fail the deployment operation, "Auto Swap" shouldn`t be trigger. if it does please do file a bug in [Project Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/new)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Release Management tools seems to apply to your problem perfectly. If you haven't tried these already you should. They are now available as a service and also works great with Azure. Use Visual Studio Team Services (previously known as Visual Studio Online) to use Release Management as a Service and use Git as version control system.

Check these resources: 
 1. [Official RM Page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/release/manage-your-release-vs)
 2. [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs)
 3. [Continuous Integration via VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/continuous-integration-vs)